# kafka json array consumer scala

Tags: json, scala, kafka-consumer-api

If we have a JSON data produced as following,

```
[{"name":"Andy", "age":30}]
[{"name":"Romen", "age":20}]
```

How to consume it on Kafka consumer using scala. I tried reading it as .select(cast(value as String)). But does not work. Please help

I read the data as following:

```
val df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker:host")   
      .option("subscribe", "topic1")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") 
      .load().selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

Comment: How did you read the message from Kafka? can you upload your code about using consumer api? if you use string deserializer, you can get the string value. your quetion needs more detailed info.

Comment: I have added the code to the question

Answer (score 0):

I just create an example code

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("Example")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

  val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(2))

  val df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "test")
      .load()

  import spark.implicits._

  val result = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .as[String]

  result.writeStream
      .format("console")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

}

this one reads the message from Kafka and writes it to the console
if you want to more info, please check here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html